# XPath extract text inside tag

Tags: xpath, html-parsing

HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="Parent"> 
  <div id="A">more tags and text</div>  
  <div id="B">more tags and text</div> 
  more tags
  <p> and text </p>
</div>
```

I would like to extract text just from the parent and the tags apart from the A and B children.
I have tried 
**/div[@class='Parent']//text()**

which extracts text from all the descendant nodes, so a made a constraint like **/div[@class='Parent']//text()[not(self::div)]**

but it did not change a thing.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/div[@class='Parent']/*[not(self::div and (@id='A' or @id='B'))]//text() | /div[@class='Parent']/text()
```

Comment: I have tried that but in this case I am not getting the text inside the tags like <em></em>